# Sogo - Changes .wox files not applicable on server

Tags: debian

I've set up SOGo on a debian server, and I want to apply some changes to `/MainUI/SOGoRootPage.wox`

I have added a heading in the file

However my changes are not reflected.

PS : I have already tried this https://sogo.nu/nc/support/faq/article/how-to-customize-the-html-2.html

Any idea how to modify the templates?

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't figured out how to make it work, but restarting Sogo once I change a file seems to work.

It's a tedious process.

I would really appreciate it if someone have a solution to this.